# `method `sub` has an incompatible type for trait` (Can sub be implemented for different structs?)

Tags: rust

I am trying to write 2 structs `Point` and `Bound` such that you can subtract a `Point` from a `Bound`.

The code:

```
struct Point {
    x:usize,
    y:usize,
}
impl Sub for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn sub(self,other:Point) -> Point {
        Point { x:self.x-other.x, y:self.y-other.y }
    }
}
struct Bound { min:Point,max:Point }
impl Sub for Bound {
    type Output = Bound;
    fn sub(self,other:Point) -> Bound {
        Bound { min:self.min-other, max:self.max-other }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
method `sub` has an incompatible type for trait

expected struct `construct::Bound`, found struct `construct::Point`

note: expected fn pointer `fn(construct::Bound, construct::Bound) -> construct::Bound`
         found fn pointer `fn(construct::Bound, construct::Point) -> construct::Bound`rustc(E0053)
main.rs(565, 9): expected struct `construct::Bound`, found struct `construct::Point`
```

Is the way I am attempting it here possible? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sub` has a parameter `Rhs`, which defaults to `Self`. `impl Sub for Bound` is short for `impl Sub<Bound> for Bound`. You would want to add `impl Sub<Point> for Bound`.

```
impl Sub<Point> for Bound {
    type Output = Bound;
    fn sub(self, other: Point) -> Bound {
        Bound { min:self.min - other, max:self.max - other }
    }
}
```

Note: this doesn't quite work because the current `impl Sub for Point` actually consumes `other` with the first `-`, leaving a "use of moved value" for the second `-`. Easiest thing is probably to just `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` on `Point`.